# MySQL LEFT OUTER JOIN performance on a local column condition

Tags: mysql, optimization

Assume the following tables, indexed on the obvious keys:

```
Table users
------------------------
id | name | has_cars
------------------------
1    Dan    0
2    Bob    0
3    Jake   1
4    Jen    1

Table cars
------------------------
id | user_id | description
------------------------
1    3         Corvette
2    3         Viper
2    3         Lamborghini
2    4         Camry
```

Is there any performance benefit to the latter of the following two queries?

```
SELECT users.*, cars.*
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN cars
ON cars.user_id = users.id
```

vs

```
SELECT users.*, cars.*
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN cars
ON users.has_cars > 0
AND cars.user_id = users.id
```

These tables, are of course for sake of example. I'm curious about the implications on much larger tables with very sparse `has_cars > 0` condition-meeting-rows. Is the optimizer able to take advantage of using a row-local condition to determine whether or not to attempt the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` per row?

EDIT: Adding another potential use case to add legitimacy to the question.

Here's a potential use case: let's say you have a table with a `type` column. For type `a` rows you want to join the `type_a` table data, for type `b` rows you want to join the `table_b` table data, etc, and here a local condition would determine whether or not to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT widgets.*, a_widgets.*, b_widgets.*, c_widgets.*
FROM widgets
LEFT OUTER JOIN a_widgets ON widgets.type = 'a' AND a_widgets.widget_id = widgets.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN b_widgets ON widgets.type = 'b' AND b_widgets.widget_id = widgets.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c_widgets ON widgets.type = 'c' AND c_widgets.widget_id = widgets.id
```

For each table join, are you getting any performance benefit from the added local condition (`widgets.type = _`)? As compared to:

```
SELECT widgets.*, a_widgets.*, b_widgets.*, c_widgets.*
FROM widgets
LEFT OUTER JOIN a_widgets ON a_widgets.widget_id = widgets.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN b_widgets ON b_widgets.widget_id = widgets.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c_widgets ON c_widgets.widget_id = widgets.id
```

(Assuming there is a `widgets.type` column, and if a row's type is `a`,`b`, or `c` there is a corresponding row in the `a_widgets`, `b_widgets` or `c_widgets` table.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not 'proper' to have redundant information in a database.  `has_cars` is redundant with `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cars WHERE user_id = ...)`.

So, once you eliminate `has_cars`, you are left with just a third option:

```
SELECT users.*, cars.*
    FROM users
    JOIN cars  ON cars.user_id = users.id
```

which is the preferred query.

Do not use `LEFT` unless you are hoping to 'find' rows missing from the right-hand table.  In that case, use the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern:

```
SELECT users.name  'Does not have any cars'
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN cars  ON cars.user_id = users.id
    WHERE cars.id IS NULL;          -- to list _only_ those without cars
```

Or to get data from `cars` *whether or not* there is a row:

```
SELECT users.name,
       cars.description  -- will be NULL if no cars
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN cars  ON cars.user_id = users.id;
```

Another variant:

```
SELECT users.name,
       COUNT(cars.id)  AS 'how many cars owned (incl 0)'
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN cars  ON cars.user_id = users.id
    GROUP BY users.id;
```

This is equivalent to that:

```
SELECT name,
       ( SELECT COUNT(cars.id) FROM cars  WHERE user_id = users.id
             )  AS 'how many cars owned (incl 0)'
    FROM users;
```

See also `GROUP_CONCAT()` as a way of listing (in a single cell) all the cars owned by each person.

Comment: Are indexes not redundant data? My example isn't a real-world example, but having a flag column could potentially yield large performance benefits on `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s. That's really what I'm asking though - will a local flag such as the one in my example cause the optimizer to not attempt to join un-qualified rows?

Comment: Adding a potential use case to the original question.

Comment: @Dan - Sorry, that design (picking among multiple tables) is usually fraught with messiness, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test. Similar setup:

```
Table users
------------------------
id | name | has_cars
------------------------
1    Dan    0
2    Bob    0
3    Jake   1
4    Jen    1

Table cars
------------------------
id | owner_id | description
------------------------
1    3          Corvette
2    3          Viper
2    3          Lamborghini
2    4          Camry
```

`users` with 1,000,000 rows
`cars` with 10,000 rows

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE users.*, cars.*
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN cars
ON cars.user_id = users.id
LIMIT 1000
```

.004s

[image: EXPLAIN 1]

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE users.*, cars.*
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN cars
ON cars.user_id = users.id
AND users.has_cars > 0
LIMIT 1000
```

.004s

[image: EXPLAIN 2]

Doesn't seem to make a significant performance difference.